# create nested json object from json object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

I have a requirement where I am querying in athena and getting back and api response like this in postman:

```
 {
            "id": "768ch23sgcjh",
            "gpsdate": "2019-04-06T13:02:08",
            "val1": "0.36233",
            "val2": "344",
            "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-49.0303646}"
        },
    {
            "id": "768ch23sgcjh",
            "gpsdate": "2019-04-06T13:02:08",
            "val1": ".22",
            "val2": "145",
            "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-49.0303646}"
        },
     {
            "id": "2453hsgdshgc",
            "gpsdate": "2019-04-06T13:02:08",
            "val1": "0.3030",
            "val2": "346",
            "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-79.0303646}"
        },
```

I want frame it some thing **like** below:

```
{
  "768ch23sgcjh" : [
     {
       "gpsdate":"2019-04-06T13:02:08",
       "val1": "0.36233",
       "val2": "344",
       "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-49.0303646}"
     }
     {
      "gpsdate":"2019-04-06T13:02:08",
       "val1": ".22",
       "val2": "145",
       "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-49.0303646}"
     }
  ]
  "2453hsgdshgc": [
     {
       "gpsdate":"2019-04-06T13:02:08",
       "val1": "0.3030",
       "val2": "346",
       "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-49.0303646}"
     }
 ]

}
```

The above format I need.So basically if for a given id there are multiple set of items then id should be appeared once.

Comment: check my solution it will produce the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let inputArray = [{
  "id": "768ch23sgcjh",
  "gpsdate": "2019-04-06T13:02:08",
  "val1": "0.36233",
  "val2": "344",
  "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-49.0303646}"
 },
 {
  "id": "768ch23sgcjh",
  "gpsdate": "2019-04-06T13:02:08",
  "val1": ".22",
  "val2": "145",
  "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-49.0303646}"
 },
 {
  "id": "2453hsgdshgc",
  "gpsdate": "2019-04-06T13:02:08",
  "val1": "0.3030",
  "val2": "346",
  "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-79.0303646}"
 }
]

let outputArray = {};
for (let item of inputArray) {
 if (!outputArray[item.id]) {
  outputArray[item.id] = [{
   gpsdate: item.gpsdate,
   val1: item.val1,
   val2: item.val2,
   loc: item.loc
  }]
 } else {
  outputArray[item.id].push({
   gpsdate: item.gpsdate,
   val1: item.val1,
   val2: item.val2,
   loc: item.loc
  })
 }

}
console.log(outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to group objects based on `id`.

```js
const arr = [{ "id": "768ch23sgcjh", "gpsdate": "2019-04-06T13:02:08", "val1": "0.36233", "val2": "344", "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-49.0303646}" }, { "id": "768ch23sgcjh", "gpsdate": "2019-04-06T13:02:08", "val1": ".22", "val2": "145", "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501,longitude=-49.0303646}" }, { "id": "2453hsgdshgc", "gpsdate": "2019-04-06T13:02:08", "val1": "0.3030", "val2": "346", "loc": "{latitude=35.8374501, longitude=-79.0303646}" }],
      result = arr.reduce((r, {id, ...rest}) => {
        r[id] = r[id] || [];
        r[id].push({...rest});
        return r;
      },{});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```